# data not retrieved in the same order

Tags: oracle, sql-order-by

I have a query which returns list of SIMs.   Each SIM is linked to a Customer.  The SIMs are in T_SIM table and Customers are in T_CUSTOMER table.  There can be more than one SIM linked to a single Customer. When returning the SIMs it returns the Customer details also.

The T_SIM table will have a foreigh key to T_CUSTOMER table.

The issue is:

1. First run the query by requesting top 100 records by doing order by CUSTOMER_CODE in ascending order.
2. Now run the same query by requesting top 1000 records by doing order by CUSTOMER_CODE in ascending order.

Here in point #2, in the results of 1000 records the first 100 records are not same as in point #1 result. The records got shuffled.  The order is not consistent.

To resolve this I have used ROWID along with order by CUSTOMER_CODE.

But the solution is not accepted by the client.

Could you please suggest any other alternative to resolve the issue. The data type of CUSTOMER_CODE is VARCHAR2

Below is the query:

```
SELECT TT.SIM_ID,
  TT.IMSI,
  TT.MSISDN,
  TT.SECONDARY_MSISDN,
  TT.CUSTOMER_ID,
  TT.SIM_STATE,
  TCU.CUSTOMER_CODE
FROM T_SIM TT

LEFT OUTER JOIN T_CUSTOMER TCU
ON TT.CUSTOMER_ID = TCU.CUSTOMER_ID

WHERE 1  = 1
AND TT.SIM_ID  IN
  (SELECT SIM_ID
  FROM
    (SELECT *
    FROM
      (SELECT Z.*,
        ROWNUM RNUM
      FROM
        (SELECT TT.SIM_ID
        FROM T_SIM TT
        LEFT OUTER JOIN T_CUSTOMER TCU
        ON TT.CUSTOMER_ID = TCU.CUSTOMER_ID
        WHERE 1           =1
        ORDER BY TCU.CUSTOMER_CODE ASC
        ) Z
      WHERE ROWNUM <= 1000
      )
    WHERE RNUM >= 0
    )
  )
ORDER BY TCU.CUSTOMER_CODE ASC
```

The result in both the cases is done order by CUSTOMER_CODE but the SIMS belonging to them are not coming in the same order.

Comment: whether your customer code is `VARCHAR2` or `NUMBER`

Comment: @Exhausted That shouldn't matter, it should still be consistent.

Comment: Please post the full query that you're using.

Comment: @Barmar What i am trying to tell is, when the `VARCHAR2` column is filled with number and tries with order by, the result will be different from the column with `NUMBER`.

Comment: @Exhausted Of course, ordering is dependent on the column type. But he's ordering by the same column in both cases, so the type doesn't change.

Comment: Please post your query.

Comment: Can you also edit your question to provide some sample data demonstrating the issue you're seeing? My guess is that there are ties in the data, but you're not ordering the tied records, so when you run your 1000 records sql, the tied rows are appearing in a different order.

Comment: Please post your query, very likely you are making rownum<1000 in the same query as order by (order by should be in subquery in this case)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that first you are limiting number of rows when selecting from t_sim (so these are selected randomly) , and just then you are ordering your output.
So what you should do, is to remove ROWNUM<1000 from inner query and
put it on the very top level like this:

```
select * from 
( TT.SIM_ID,
  TT.IMSI,
  TT.MSISDN,
  TT.SECONDARY_MSISDN,
  TT.CUSTOMER_ID,
  TT.SIM_STATE,
  TCU.CUSTOMER_CODE
FROM T_SIM TT

LEFT OUTER JOIN T_CUSTOMER TCU
ON TT.CUSTOMER_ID = TCU.CUSTOMER_ID

WHERE 1  = 1
AND TT.SIM_ID  IN
  (SELECT SIM_ID
  FROM
    (SELECT *
    FROM
      (SELECT Z.*,
        ROWNUM RNUM
      FROM
        (SELECT TT.SIM_ID
        FROM T_SIM TT
        LEFT OUTER JOIN T_CUSTOMER TCU
        ON TT.CUSTOMER_ID = TCU.CUSTOMER_ID
        WHERE 1           =1
        ORDER BY TCU.CUSTOMER_CODE ASC
        ) Z
      )
    WHERE RNUM >= 0
    )
  )
ORDER BY TCU.CUSTOMER_CODE ASC
) where rownum<1000
```

Because first you want to make complete ordered result set and just then display 1000 top records of sim cards ordered by customer_code.

Comment: also I didn't mentioned this in my answer, but what is the poit of puting condition rnum>=0? doesn't make sense to me